# Receiving error when using UtilityBarAPI in Winter '18

Tags: lightning-aura-components, error, winter18

I'm trying to set a custom icon in a Utility Bar component using the new Utility Bar Component in Lightning.

**TestComponent.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <force:utilityBarAPI aura:id="utilitybar" />
    <lightning:button label="Set Panel Header Icon" onclick="{! c.customizeUtilityPanel }" />
</aura:component>
```

**TestComponentController.js**

```
({
    customizeUtilityPanel : function(component, event, helper) {
        var utilityAPI = component.find("utilitybar");
        utilityAPI.getAllUtilityInfo().then(function(response) {
            var myUtilityInfo = response[0];

            utilityAPI.setPanelHeaderIcon({utilityId: myUtilityInfo.id, sldsKey: "clock"});
            utilityAPI.setUtilityIcon({utilityId: myUtilityInfo.id, sldsKey: "frozen"});

            utilityAPI.openUtility({utilityId: myUtilityInfo.id});
        });
    }
})
```

But I'm receiving following error in browser console:

> aura_prod.js:922 null "Error: Invalid or missing icon `undefined`"
>   (anonymous) @ aura_prod.js:922 aura_prod.js:849 Uncaught (in promise)
>   Error: Invalid or missing icon `undefined` b @ aura_prod.js:849 Async
>   Call d @ internal.js:1 b @ aura_prod.js:849 d.then @ internal.js:1

I'm using following `Console Developer Guide` and the new `force:utilityBarAPI` component introduced in `Winter '18`.

Does anyone have any idea why I'm unable to use the method to set an Icon in Utility bar component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it to work, but honestly it was more of a trial and error method. I suspect we are running into a documentation bug of some kind. The documentation states *`setUtilityIcon({sldsKey, utilityId})`* , but the error seems to indicate a key "**icon**" was missing. So i modified the code as follows and UtilityApi started to work as expected. Check the before and after images for the working scenario.

> **Controller:**

```
    var utilityAPI = component.find("utilitybar");
    utilityAPI.getEnclosingUtilityId().then(function(response) {
        utilityAPI.setUtilityLabel({label : "Hello World", utilityId : response});
        utilityAPI.setUtilityIcon({icon : "insert_tag_field", utilityId : response });
    });
```

> **Before SetUtilityIcon()**

[image]

> **After SetUtilityIcon()**

[image]

We will be able to notice that the icon and label changed to "insert tag field" & "Hello World" respectively . And i guess callback is optional.